# Import python file into another python file

Tags: python

Before this is marked as duplicate please read the full problem.

So I have a folder structure like this:

```
main.py
|
|_one
  |_ one.py
  |_ file.txt
```

What i'm doing is, importing *one.py* into *main.py* and calling a function. My py files are,

**main.py**

```py
import one 
one.f1('test')
```

**one.py**

```py
def f1(param):
  with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
  print(f+param)
```

When I run *main.py*, I keep getting this error : `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.txt'.`

I have also tries `os.path.abspath()` but still no luck. Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The path is computed from the root directory not the directory the the calling code resides in. Try `one/file.txt` for Linux environment.

Comment: Well, that worked, but I'm getting this Pickle error `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Node' on <module '__main__' from '/Users/paul-mac/Work/sums/orient.py'>`

Comment: Post the code , stacktrace and  related resources, then the community can help.

Comment: @hrishikeshpaul: That's an entirely unrelated error, in code you haven't posted. You're welcome to ask a new question with a [MCVE], but asking new questions in comments on the answer to your actual question is frowned upon.

Comment: Note: I'd suggest not using `one/file.txt` since that'll only work if your working directory is the same as `main.py`'s. `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'file.txt')` (from within `one.py`) will find the data file relative to the source file, which works regardless of your working directory.